# Syntax error in UPDATE statement vb and ms.access as database

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make medical record application for my assignment. I found this error to edit data patient.

Please help and sorry for my bad grammar

```
Dim aksesedit As String = "Update tbpasien set " & _
                "Nama_Pasien='" & txtnamapasien.Text & "', " & _
                "Jenis_Kelamin='" & cmbjk.Text & "'," & _
                "Tempat_Pasien='" & txttempatlahir.Text & "', " & _
                "Tanggal_Lahir='" & tanggallahir.Text & "', " & _
                "Alamat='" & txtalamat.Text & "', " & _
                "Kelurahan_Desa='" & txtkeldesa.Text & "', " & _
                "Kecamatan='" & txtkec.Text & "', " & _
                "Kota_Kabupaten='" & txtkotakab.Text & "', " & _
                "No_Telepon_HP='" & txtnotelp.Text & "', " & _
                "Agama='" & cmbagama.Text & "', " & _
                "Kewarganegaraan='" & cmbwarga.Text & "', " & _
                "Status_Pernikahan='" & cmbstatus.Text & "', " & _
                "Pekerjaan='" & txtpekerjaan.Text & "', " & _
                "where No_RM='" & txtnorm.Text & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(aksesedit)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

syntax error in update was on here

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

For "Tanggal_Lahir" i used datetimepicker, cmb=combobox, txt=textbox
Thanks

Comment: Please post the full error info so we can see exactly what the program is saying when it happens.

Comment: The first thing you should do is stop creating SQL that way and use SQL Parameters.  Among other things the code will be easier to read and the SQL harder to botch.

Comment: @plutonix im not used sql, i used ms.access

Comment: `"Update tbpasien set ..."` is a SQL Statement.  Dont build SQL that way,

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan i cant post image :( 
it said OleDbException was unhandled
syntax error in UPDATE statement.

its point at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @Plutonix ahh i see,  but before this i try that code for edit data used ms.access and its successed.. so which code to use for ms.access?thanks before :)

Comment: Have you tried `msgbox(aksesedit)` so that you can see the entire string as it is going to be passed to Access?

Comment: Just to make sure it gets a mention... it looks like you're currently vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  I recommend you read more...

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah i learn vb too instant, so not really understand bout vb things hehe, but problem resolved, thanks to tony, the problem just about the coma, and that code can use for ms. access too  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no comma before the WHERE clause:

```
 "Pekerjaan='" & txtpekerjaan.Text & "' " & _
                "where No_RM='" & txtnorm.Text & "'"
```